# How to find arithmetic return and cummulativ return in R (for bonds)?

Tags: r, return, stock

How do I find daily return and cummulativ return (arithmetic) on bond(s) via quantmod? I have tried respectively "dailyreturn" and "cumprod" packages on these two operations with stocks and indexes, but It seems as it can be wrong when I`m doing it with bonds, or?

Task 1d) asks me to find daily return, meanwhile 1e) asks me to find the cummulative arithmetic return (investing 100dollars). Later I have to plot all these.

```
enter code here




################1a)######################
####Task 1a) asks me to open security data. I should use stocks, indexes 
#and bonds. 

library(quantmod)
start <- as.Date("2012-12-31")
end   <- as.Date("2018-12-31")


tckrs  <- c("AAPL","TSLA")
Stocks <-  getSymbols(tckrs, auto.assign = TRUE, from = start, to=end)
Index  <- getSymbols("^NYA", auto.assign = TRUE, from = start, to=end)

DGS10 <- getSymbols(Symbols = "DGS10", src = "FRED", auto.assign = FALSE)
DGS10<- na.omit(DGS10)
Bond <-DGS10["2012-12-31/2018-12-31"]
View(Bond)
Bond


#####################################################################
################1b)###################
########Task 1b) asks me to use adjusted close and make a timeseries 
#plot 

####Stocks####

colnames(AAPL) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
colnames(TSLA) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")      
colnames(NYA) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")

AAPL.Adj <- AAPL[,6]
TSLA.Adj <- TSLA[,6]

Stocks <-cbind(AAPL,TSLA)
head(Basket)

myColors <- c("red", "darkgreen")
plot(x = Stocks[,"Adjusted"],main = "Stock prices", ylim = c(0, 450), 
major.ticks= "years",
minor.ticks = FALSE, col = "red")
lines(x = Stocks[,"Adjusted.1"], col = "darkgreen")
title(xlab="Time",ylab="Adjusted close" )

####Index####

colnames(NYA) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
plot(x = NYA[,"Adjusted"],main = "Index price",xlab= "Time",ylab="Adjusted 
Close", major.ticks= "years",
minor.ticks = FALSE, col = "brown")
title(xlab = "Time", ylab="Adj. C.")
legend(x="center",col = "brown",legend = c("NYA"), lty = 1)


####Bond####
plot(x=Bond[,"DGS10"], main= "Bond", xlab="Time",ylab="Rent",major.ticks = 
"years", col = "purple")
legend(x="topleft",col="purple",legend = c("DSG10"),lty=1)
#######################################  
########################## 1c)########################################
#1c) wants me to find and plot the daily arithmetic return for 
#each security (Im not sure how to cope with bonds in this case, but I 
#think that I did it the right way)

TSLA_return_plot <- plot(dailyReturn(Ad(TSLA), type="arithmetic", 
main="Daily return"),type="l")
title( xlab = "Time",ylab = "Percent")

AAPL_returnplot <- plot(dailyReturn(Ad(AAPL), type="arithmetic", 
main="Daily return"),type="l")
title( xlab = "Time",ylab = "Percent")

NYA_returnplot <-  plot(dailyReturn(Ad(NYA), type="arithmetic", 
main="Daily return"),type="l")
title( xlab = "Time",ylab = "Percent")
NYA_returnplot

TB10YR_returnplot <- plot(dailyReturn(Bond)/(365*100), type = "l")


######################### 1d)########################################
######## Task 1d) asks me to find the cummulativ return for 100$ invested 
#(Again, Im wondering if Im doing it the right way with the bond)
TSLA_cummulativR  <- 100*cumprod(1+dailyReturn(Ad(TSLA)))
AAPL_cummulativR  <- 100*cumprod(1+dailyReturn(Ad(AAPL)))
NYA_cummulativR   <- 100*cumprod(1+dailyReturn(Ad(NYA))) 
TB10YR_cummulativR <- 100*cumprod(1+(dailyReturn(Bond)))
TB10YR_cummulativR



plot(NYA_cummulativR,type = "l", main = "Cummulativ daily Return (100 
invested)",col = "2", xlab="Time",ylab="Return")
title(xlab = "Time", ylab = "C. return", col="green")

plot(AAPL_cummulativR, type="l", main="Cummulativ daily Retun (100 
invested)")
title(xlab = "Time", ylab = "C. return")

plot(TSLA_cummulativR, type="l",ylim = c(0,1400), main = "Cummulativ daily 
Return (100 invested)")
title(xlab = "Time", ylab = "C. return")

plot(TB10YR_cummulativR, type = "l")


#######################1e)###########################################
```

Comment: Hi, we would be glad to help. Would you mind putting the code onto your post, it's hard to read off the image.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please improve your question by adding: 1. some sample data. 2. The code of your attempts to solve the problem or achieve what you want. 3. The errors or unexpected behavior you observe in your code and 4. The expected result. Images in lieu of code aren't good, as it's difficult to copy and paste, please share actual data, code and output. **Help us help you**

Comment: Im new at this. Feel free to ask further questions. I have been programming in only 2 weeks, so it may be not be a quality product XD @StupidWolf

Comment: ^ here it is @PavoDive

Comment: I have uploaded the wholde script with comments on what the tasks ask me to find